# Android Studio Add Local Project to Gradle

Tags: gradle, android-studio

[image: screenshot]
I've attached a screenshot of my current project setup but am having issues getting the code from the "library" project to work in the "SampleApp" project.  My project build.gradle contains the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And my settings.gradle contains the following:

```
include ':SampleApp'
include ':library'
```

My SampleApp build.gradle contains the following:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile project(':library')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

And my library build.gradle contains the following:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 11
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
        }
    }
}
```

The strange part is that if I try to include a piece of code from the library project in my SampleApp project, I can add the relevant, use the AndroidStudio feature to add the proper imports and there are no errors.  However as soon as I go to build, I get an error that says my package does not exist.  I've also gone into the Android Studio project properties and added library as a dependency of SampleApp.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your library's **build.gradle** instead of this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

do this:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```